# AR.js Multi-camera smartphones selecting the regular lens

Tags: ar.js

In `AR.JS` demo,
Android phones that have multiple rear cameras tend to use the wrong lens, such as a telescopic lens. For example, Huawei mate 20 pro uses the 3x lens.
How do I select the right camera to use?

Comment: Not sure it will work or not in your case. But try using Firefox Mobile. It let you choose Back/Front camera on my phone. Maybe it will let you choose another back camera option

Comment: I've got the same issue in 8th wall. Object have different proportions on differente devices because they use different lenses.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue, i tried using opera, it detects all cameras and allows you to choose the one you want. but, in my case (Samsung Note 10+) the zoom cameras and front camera work,yet the main one doesn't.
Check if it works with your phone.